# Wordpress - Column one below the other on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I just started a wordpress site and have the following layout:
[image]

The red lines indicate columns, so I have an element with 3 columns with the title and description and another element with 3 columns with the prices. This is because I want all the prices on the same height of each other.

Unfortunately, when viewing the site on a mobile phone, it looks like this:
[image]

So it first displays all three titles and descriptions and then all three prices.

What I want is to have the prices below it's corresponding description on mobile.

What is the best way to achieve that?
Is there a plugin I can use to achieve this?

Btw: I'm using the newest version of WordPress

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's nice that you have added images to describe the problem but people here need to see your markup. Site link or a quick demo would be better I guess.

Comment: @ManojKumar thanks for you input, it can be viewed live here https://wp.fh-cosmetics.ch/gesicht/apparative-kosmetik/ :-)

Comment: Do you want it to display like this on mobile? https://imgur.com/zVjc9XX

Comment: Unfortunately not, I want it to be like this: Titel 1 then below Description 1 then below Price 1. Followed by Titel 2, description 2, price 2 etc.

Comment: You can move the blocks with .js to proper display but I think that could be a bad solution. Use only 3 columns and put all the content in the 3 columns. Put some classes on the different blocks (title, list and prices block) and then you can control the columns with css. There are many ways to keep the same height of the prices with css.

Comment: If you are using a page builder like WPBakery there must be options to hide/show elements on Desktop/Mobile.